# Changing auth_redirect() page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I understand that the `auth_redirect()` checks if a user is logged in, if not it redirects them to the login page then come back to the previous page on success. I need that functionality on my website and I have that.

For example, I wanted one of the pages to access only by logged in users, if they tried to access the page then they need to login first then on success come back to that page. I have the following code on my `function.php`.

```
if ( is_page('user_only') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    auth_redirect();
}
```

The problem is I have a custom login/registration page and instead of the default WordPress login page, I want the `auth_redirect();` to use my custom login/registration page.

The `auth_redirect();` is using the `wp-login.php` and I want to use my custom page `account/index.php`.
Can this be done? I know about `wp_redirect( url, );` but I don't think I need that since its purpose is for redirection only and not for authentication.

Comment: If you check the code of the function, you see that it uses `wp_login_url` to determine the login URL to redirect to, and if you look at that one again, you see that there is a filter named `login_url` you can hook into, to modify it.

Comment: @CBroe -  I checked the `general_template.php` then on `wp_login_url()` function, I've changed the `wp-login.php` to the custom login page and it works. Unfortunately, it didn't redirect back to the previous address, it just on the account page and logged in.

Comment: `wp_login_url` allows you to specify the URL the system will redirect the user to after successful login, and the `login_url` filter also gets it passed in. All you have to do is add it to your login URL as a query string parameter named `redirect_to`

Comment: @CBroe - Can you elaborate it with a code? Upon changing the `wp-login.php` on `wp_login_url()` function in the `general_template.php` with my custom login page, I get this url `http://localhost:5597/website/custom-login/?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5597%2Fwebsite%2FuserOnly%2F&reauth=1` when I go to the page that only logged in user can access. As you can see, base on the url, it should be redirecting back to `userOnly` page when the authentication from `custom-login` is successful. But it doesn't work, after successfull login, it's just on the profile of the `custom-login page`.

Comment: Well what exactly does it mean, when you say you have a “custom login/registration page”? Did you just change the layout, but it is still using default WP functionality? If not, and you are handling login on your own there or interfere in any other major way, it might not work any more as intended.

Comment: @CBroe - I'm using `woocommerce` and its default `login/registration` page. What I mean custom login page is the login/registration page of woocommerce, I didn't change anything on it. I actually want to replace the default login/registration page of Wordpress into the  login/registration page of woocommerce but upon reading other  similar issue, they said that the `wp-login.php` cannot be completely change since it is hardcoded unless you modify the core of wordpress. So, yep, the custom login/registration page is just the page of woocommerce.

Comment: Ah, then you’ll have to use a different filter, WooCommerce bypasses the normal WP login flow a bit. https://iconicwp.com/blog/redirect-users-woocommerce-login-registration/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the child theme function, it is located on:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\your-website\wp-content\themes\your-theme\functions.php

Then at the bottom of the code, **insert these 3 functions**.

**FUNCTION #1**
Change the default login URL which is `wp-login.php` to your custom page. For example `https://localhost/my-website/my-account/`.

```
/**Function to change the default `wp-login.php` with your custom login page **/
add_filter( 'login_url', 'new_login_page', 10, 3 );
function new_login_page( $login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth ) {
    $login_page = home_url( '/my-account/' ); //use the slug of your custom login page.
    return add_query_arg( 'redirect_to', $redirect, $login_page );
}
```

**FUNCTION #2**
In my case, I wanted to `redirect` users into `Sign in/Registration` page if they wanted to access the `wishlist` or wanted to proceed into the `checkout` page, 
after successfully logged in they will redirect back into the previous page.

```
/**Function to redirect into `logged-in/Registration` page if not logged-in**/
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_if_not_logged_in');
function redirect_if_not_logged_in() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in() && (is_page('wishlist') || is_page('checkout'))) {
        auth_redirect(); //redirect into my custom login page
    }
}
```

**FUNCTION #3**
The last thing is to handle the redirection back to the previous page after successfully logged in.

For some reason, if you are using the default login page which is the `wp-login.php` and not a custom login page, the redirection works without using the below code after successfully logged-in and I'm still searching for an explanation on it since I'm just new in WordPress, I think it has something to do with the custom login page of Woocommerce.
Otherwise, you can use the below code to redirect back to the previous page after successful logged-in.

```
//function to create the redirection url
function redirect_link($redirect){
    //extract the redirection url, in my case the url with rederiction is https://my-website/my-account/?redirect_to=https://my-website/the-slug/ then I need to get the
    //https://my-website/the-slug by using the `strstr` and `substr` function of php.
    $redirect = substr(strstr($redirect, '='), 1); 

    //decode the url back to normal using the urldecode() function, otherwise the url_to_postid() won't work and will give you a different post id.
    $redirect = urldecode($redirect);

    //get the id of page that we weanted to redirect to using url_to_postid() function of wordpress.
    $redirect_page_id = url_to_postid( $redirect );

    //get the post using the id of the page
    $post = get_post($redirect_page_id); 

    //convert the id back into its original slug
    $slug = $post->post_name;

    if(!isset($slug) || trim($slug) === ''){ //if slug is empty or if doesn't exist redirect back to shop
        return get_permalink(get_page_by_path('shop'));
    }
    //re-create the url using get_permalink() and get_page_by_path() function.
    return get_permalink(get_page_by_path($slug));
}

/**Function to redirect back to previous page after succesfful logged-in**/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'redirect_back_after_logged_in');
function redirect_back_after_logged_in($redirect) {
    return redirect_link($redirect);
}

/**Function to redirect back to previous page after succesfful registration**/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'cs_redirect_after_registration');
function cs_redirect_after_registration( $redirect ){
    return redirect_link($redirect);
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it in terms of security and bug issues, I hope someone will point out the right way if there is, I will edit this if I found something better.